# Pycharm 2019.2.4 does not reconize pyvisa commmand: import pyvisa

Tags: python, pyvisa

PC WIN10
Pycharm 2019.2.4
Interface: USB
DMM: Agilent 344010a

Ran the following command from the command prompt

```
PIP LIST:

pip 19.2.3
PyVISA 1.4
Setuptools 41.2.0
```

Commands in Pycharm:

```
Import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager('')
```

Response:

```
Error: import Pyvisa, ModuleNotFounDERROR: No module named 'pyvisa'
```

Comment: Do you have pyvisa installed?

Comment: You need to check if your PyCharm is getting the same Python version that is be using by your pip list, search the Python sdk config in your settings and set the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed pyvisa in your environment? You can do this by going into Pycharm->Preferences->Project Interpreter and click the "+" sign to look for PyVISA and have pip install it for you. You should be able to import it afterwards.